# Xamarin Forms iOS default app icon white background

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, icons, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to distribute my xamarin forms application (iOS) using appcenter.ms and the app icon initially when it is installing it seems to be the right one however when the installation is finished my app icon is replaced by the default app icon of iOS (white background). The app works fine, Push Notifications work fine, the issue is only those icons: home app icon, notification icon, settings icon, etc. I haven't used TestFlight at all. I have only used appcenter and visual studio 2017 15.9.13. Any ideas why are those icons replaced by the default white background one?

[App Icon during Installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCYrY.jpg) [App Icon when Installation is finished](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzhC0.jpg)

I am using Asset Catalogs:
[Solution Asset Catalogs Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXLii.png)

Info.plist: 2 entries added:
[2 entries added screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYYay.png)

Resources folder structure and files:
[Resources folder structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV4bT.png)

Info.plist Visual Assets:
[Info.plist Visual Assets screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCm9w.png)

This is part of the appcenter logs. I don't see any problem regarding icons during build:

Copying file from '/Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/My.APP/obj/iPhone/Release/actool/bundle/AppIcon40x40@2x~ipad.png' to '/Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/My.APP/bin/iPhone/Release/My.APP.app/AppIcon40x40@2x~ipad.png'
  Copying file from '/Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/My.APP/obj/iPhone/Release/actool/bundle/AppIcon76x76~ipad.png' to '/Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/My.APP/bin/iPhone/Release/My.APP.app/AppIcon76x76~ipad.png'

Comment: Did you set App icons in your info.plist?

Comment: info.plist-->Visual assets-->App icons--> Source

Comment: @AndroDevil, do I need to? I thought using Asset Catalogs would be enough. However I have a couple of entries in info.plist as you can see in images attached.

Comment: @AndroDevil "info.plist-->Visual assets-->App icons--> Source", I attached some images

Comment: did you solved ?

Comment: @AndroDevil no man and I think I have tried everything. I am starting to think this happens because I am not using testflight.

Comment: Can you just create a new project and add your icon there to see if it works?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT you mean, creating a new app, adding my icons, linking it to appcenter, creating a build configuration, adding my certtificate p12 and provision file, you mean all that to see if it works. First, can you please tell me if I have done all things required to make this thing to work? By the way, I forgot to mention that in a Simulator icons are displayed correctly.

Comment: First, I think you have already done all things to make it work. You can have a look at the document about more detail:[application-spotlight-and-settings-icons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/app-icons?tabs=windows#application-spotlight-and-settings-icons).  Second, no need to link it to appcenter, just create a new sample project and add icons, then run in your real device to see if it works. Also, if it works on a simulator, I would recommend you to try some other icon images(make sure the icon image is `.png` format).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I have tried in a simulator with different icons and all good, my icons and other icons work fine in a simulator but they are not being displayed in a device distributed by appcenter.

Comment: Don't test in simulator, run the test project on real device with different icons.

Comment: I tried in a device and all good. Finally, I deployed it to the app store manually and got approved and now my app is in the app store and icons are fine. Not sure what's wrong with appcenter, I will try to connect appcenter to the app store connect for deploying, I hope it won't cause any issue to the icons.